# How do I refer to a folder/file directory on Linux Azure VM in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, windows, azure

```
fs.createReadStream("Reference\\" + countryIn + " ADDRESS REF DATA.csv")
```

On windows this line works fine to find the reference data starting with the country code we input, but on Linux I get the error of

```
events.js:287
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'Reference\UK ADDRESS REF DATA.csv'
Emitted 'error' event on ReadStream instance at:
    at internal/fs/streams.js:132:12
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:155:23) {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'Reference\\UK ADDRESS REF DATA.csv'
}
```

The Reference folder is contained next to the script that's running, and the reference file in that folder. How do I properly refer to it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. Linux appears to not accept the \ as an escape character for a directory slash, so it works if I change the line to

```
fs.createReadStream("./Reference/" + countryIn + " ADDRESS REF DATA.csv")
```

The ./ in front appears necessary as well